# Magento 2 Set Grid/List view on an individual category basis

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I am looking for a way to individually set the default view for each category to **grid/list** as opposed to the sitewide option.

**I have found this solution:**
https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/251172/66845

> 1. Does anyone know if this still works in v2.3 and v2.4?
> 2. If so, how do I install the module provided by Himmat Paliwal

Answer (score 0):

May be that extension working.

1. Download the extension from given link.
2. Now unzip the download zip file.
3. Put the `\MyCompany\CustomListMode` folder into magento on following location : `app\code`
4. so extension path like this : `app\code\MyCompany\CustomListMode`
5. Run following command from CLI:

   ```
   php bin/magento cache:clean
   php bin/magento cache:flush
   php bin/magento indexer:reindex
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   ```

Comment: Thanks for that. I installed the extension but got the following error when trying to display the category page in admin: Class W3solver\Customcategorymode\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Showmode does not exist [] []

Comment: Confirm that file is exist on the given location or not.